# Image trouble with GUI's

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hey guys I am a beginner programmer and am currently working on GUI's. I know how to add an image to a JFrame's content pane and get it to show up but what I have to do is when I play this game in my gui, each room I enter must display a new image in the GUI. Below is my createRooms method.

```
    private void createRooms(){

    Room outside, theater, pub, lab, office, transporter1, transporter2;

    // create the rooms
    outside = new Room("outside the main entrance of the university");

    theater = new Room("in a lecture theater");
    pub = new Room("in the campus pub");
    lab = new Room("in a computing lab");
    office = new Room("in the computing admin office");
    transporter1 = new TransporterRoom("in space");
    transporter2 = new TransporterRoom("in a weird dimension");

    // initialise room exits
    outside.setExit("east", theater);
    outside.setExit("south", lab);
    outside.setExit("west", transporter2);

    theater.setExit("west", outside);

    //             transporter2.getExit();

    pub.setExit("east", outside);

    lab.setExit("north", outside);
    lab.setExit("east", office);

    office.setExit("west", lab);

    currentRoom = outside;  // start game outside
```

}

What I am trying to do is add an imageIcon to each of these rooms and I am not entirely sure on how to do that. Thanks ahead of time and let me know if you need any more of my code!

edit: here is the code for the room class, thanks codeNinja for pointing that out

```
private String description;
private HashMap<String, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
public static ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();




/**
 * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
 * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
 * "an open court yard".
 * @param description The room's description.
 */
public Room(String description) 
{
    this.description = description;
    exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
    image = new ImageIcon("images");
    rooms.add(this);
}

/**
 * Define an exit from this room.
 * @param direction The direction of the exit.
 * @param neighbor  The room to which the exit leads.
 */
public void setExit(String direction, Room neighbor) 
{
    exits.put(direction, neighbor);
}

/**
 * @return The short description of the room
 * (the one that was defined in the constructor).
 */
public String getShortDescription()
{
    return description;
}

/**
 * Return a description of the room in the form:
 *     You are in the kitchen.
 *     Exits: north west
 * @return A long description of this room
 */
public String getLongDescription()
{
    return ("You are " + description + ".\n" + getExitString());
}

/**
 * Return a string describing the room's exits, for example
 * "Exits: north west".
 * @return Details of the room's exits.
 */
private String getExitString()
{
    String returnString = "Exits:";
    Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
    for(String exit : keys) {
        returnString += " " + exit;
    }
    return returnString;
}

/**
 * Return the room that is reached if we go from this room in direction
 * "direction". If there is no room in that direction, return null.
 * @param direction The exit's direction.
 * @return The room in the given direction.
 */
public Room getExit(String direction) 
{
    return exits.get(direction);
}
```

}

Comment: The code for the `Room` class will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.
First you can add JLabel to you contentPane and set image to that JLabel. But this is not best way becouse if you want to put component over it you must use Absolute Layout.
Second one is to put JPanel in frame and implement paintComponent method.

```
JPanel imagePanel= new JPanel(){
   @Override
   public void painComponent(Graphics g){
      super.painComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(yourPrefImage,0,0,sizeOfPanelX(Frame),sizeOfPanelY(Frame),null);
   } 
}
```